# Validations in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` in my current project with `MS CRM` as the backend. (Hence no entity framework). We have a series of very long pages (*about 10-15*) pages that the customer has to fill as part of their application. When each page is saved, the data will be stored in the corresponding entity in `CRM`. After they fill all the 15 pages, they submit their application.

The requirement is that the business doesn't want to enforce page level validations. Since the pages are too long, they want to let the users save data without filling the entire page in one go. At the end of the 15 pages, on the "Review your application" page, they want to run all the validation rules on the saved data and check for requiredness.

1. Does *MVC validations* work in this scenario or do we have to write a custom library that can run all the rules?
2. Can we inherhit the models from IValidatableObject Interface and call Model.Validate for all 15 pages on the "Review" page?

Comment: You can approach for 1st solution, Take all field from DB and Validate in c# code itself, that only solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

MVC Support Validation on more than one way as I use

1- on the Model using Data Annotation  on Models (Per Property)

2- on The Controller which represente your view to add Data Annotation over the current Controller

3- validate using Jquery on HTML object like HTML

4- validate using Roles on Razor Engine with If conditions / Switch case

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of view models and then call modelstae.isvalid on each one and handle the errors in a way that you will be able to show them in the preview page.

However, this is unnecessarily complex and from a UX perspective is going to be a suboptimal experience. I would rethink very carefully the requirement for a preview page where all errors are aggregated and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.
You can enable and disable validation for whole application in Global page.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

you can also pragmatically set ClientValidationEnabled to false for your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use formData validation, which is used in realtime environment, it is much helpful, which can be applied to each and every required field control, give sample code have a look

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(postedFormData["UserName"])))
        {
            LoginViewModel.ReturnMessage.Clear();
            LoginViewModel.ReturnMessage.Add("Enter Username");
            LoginViewModel.ReturnStatus = false;
        }
     else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(postedFormData["Password"])))
        {
            LoginViewModel.ReturnMessage.Clear();
            LoginViewModel.ReturnMessage.Add("Enter Password");
            LoginViewModel.ReturnStatus = false;
        }
```

when you passing the username and password in a method then call it in this way

```
  LoginViewModel = LoginApplicationService.ValidateLogIn(LoginViewModel.LoginDataModel.UserName, LoginViewModel.LoginDataModel.Password)
```

which is used in MVC 4.5, it works with empty text field along with custom validation like, Invalid user and so on.. for validation methods you have to customize the code, above is just a hint but very effective.